# Using Kendo grid under Angular, how to modify the left spacing?

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, grid, telerik

[Left spacing of the group to modify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oezh.png)

As illustrated above, I would like to modify the left spacing of the group in a telerik kendo grid under Angular, anyone has any idea how to do it ?

I'm trying to change the width of the following td using the following css :

```
.k-group-cell {
  width: 2px;
}
```

However, it is not working ...

Comment: can you please post a snippet in stackblitz, would be easier to get help if you share more details, like skin you are using, maybe bootstrap 3 4??

Comment: Great name you got there